# How to identify an separate service application is running or not from another app

Tags: android, service

I have two applications. One just contains `Service` and from another app I start this `Service` app. Like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(context.getString(R.string.package_location_service),
            context.getString(R.string.package_location_service) + ".GetLocationService"); // package name and class name
serviceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

But I want to check whether that `Service` is already running or not! If it's a service inside the same app then I can check whether it's running or not by

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName){
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)Application.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
        if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

But how to check in my scenario? Any help?